# BootstrapVue Components Not Being Converted into HTML

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

My components are rendering to the client page exactly as written in BootstrapVue, so I'm seeing `<b-button>` literally rendered to the client page:

```
<b-button data-v-3d7e72245 id="myBtn" variant="outline-primary">Click Me</b-button>
```

Shouldn't this be converted into standard HTML during the Vue render process and have the bootstrap classes added automatically?

I'm new to Vue, so I could be missing something obvious - but I'm not seeing any errors when running 'npm run build' in the command line, or in the web console/Vue dev tools.

Header.vue:

```
<template>
  <header id="Header">
    <ApplyBtn btnText="Click Me" />
  </header>
</template>

<script>
  import ApplyBtn from './header/ApplyBtn.vue'

  export default {
  name: 'Header',
  components: {
  ApplyBtn
  }
  }
</script>
```

Main.js:

```
import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import 'intersection-observer' 
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue' 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import '/scss/global/duo-theme.scss'

new Vue({
    vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#App')

Vue.config.devtools = true
Vue.config.productionTip = false

// Custom widgets
Vue.component('applybtn', require('./components/global/header/ApplyBtn.vue').default);

window.Vue = Vue; 
Vue.use(BootstrapVue); 
Vue.use(IconsPlugin);
```

Package.json:

```
   {
  "name": "VueBS",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "acorn": "^8.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-scss": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.10.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.12.0",
    "jquery": "^1.12.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.12",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.3.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing your `Vue.use` before you create your Vue instance.

Change this

```js
new Vue({
    vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#App')

Vue.use(BootstrapVue); 
Vue.use(IconsPlugin);
```

To this

```js
Vue.use(BootstrapVue); 
Vue.use(IconsPlugin); 

new Vue({
    vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#App');
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I thought the Vue object would need to be created before registering those usings, guess not... my button is now rendering as expected. Really appreciate your insight here!